# Can I safely use root for I9500, if I have a GT-I9506?

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-s-4

Can I safely use root for I9500, if I have a I9506?
Or will it cause any problems?
If not, what root can I use?

I can't seem to find the I9506 anywhere on the internet. Is it a new edition or is it because it's nordic?

EDIT: Bear with me I'm new to android.

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2529064 XDA has threads for the i9506. It is a very different device from the i9500, differing hardware, partitions, bootloaders etc. I would steer away from ANYTHING that does not specifically mention your EXACT device model. ROMs for the 9500 are 100% guaranteed not to work and will brick your device. There isn't much dev work on the i9506 so do read threads on XDA and elsewhere to see what your options are.

Comment: I just wanted to add to the "Bear with me I'm new to android." You've already done THE most important thing, and that is read up and ask questions. Rooting etc takes a few minutes... unless it goes wrong. It is horrible when it does, but if you know the steps and you know what you are doing it can mitigate that sinking feeling! The more you read up the better for you. Just remember you must see your exact device variant before flashing anything, and ALWAYS ALWAYS ALWAYS backup everything (including your backups!)

Answer (score 1):

If you're thinking of Chainfire's CF-Auto-Root, don't use the files for I9500, I9505, I9505G. Chances are it might not work.

However, XDA has a thread with a [pre-rooted GT-I9506 stock ROM](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2597058). You can try that instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [rooting method for I9506](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2529064).

**NOTE:** I'm not responsible for any cause of problems that happens to your phone while doing the rooting.